# How to address the reader to visit our supplementary material? (is it okay?)

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission, supporting-information

Because of words limitation, I put many of important things in supplementary material. So, is it okay to ask the reader to visit our supplementary material in manuscript? For example,

> We encourage the one to visit Supplementary Material to avoid misinterpretation.

If it is okay, where is the best to put this clause?

Comment: The journal publishing your paper may have policies for maintaining access to supplementary material. As the editor.

Comment: thank you for your reminder. As I checked at the very first volume of the journal publication (2005), it still keep the supplementary material.

Answer (score 4):

Concerning your main question: I would expect that you refer to every part of the supplementary material somewhere in the text. So yes, it is okay to direct the reader to the supplementary material. But I recommend to be specific.

However, it is not okay to "put many of important things in supplementary material". The really important things should be part of the main manuscript.

Comment: yes I refer every part of sup. material in my text. And I absolutely agree with your opinion that important things should be part of the main manuscript. 

Long story short, my paper getting bigger and bigger, and I used all the given slot of sup. material. I finished my conclusion part and as I read again my manuscript, I feel like I need to emphasize the sup. material to the reader in the conclusion part.

Answer (score 2):

Your paper, *without any of the supplementary material*, should be clear and not easily misinterpreted, even if it must be superficial due to word limits. It should also be clear as someone reads along *when they can view supplementary material to find more depth* if they are interested. You should not need to inform the reader separately that they should read the supplementary material, your references to it should be sufficient on their own.

An exception may be journals that move substantial entire parts of the paper to supplementary material, like all or most of the methods section. In that case, usually the journal has its own way to direct the reader to "supplementary methods section" or "online methods" or similar; look at other papers published in the same journal for guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your thought. In my opinion, my paper, without sup. material, is not clear enough and easily misinterpreted, and this is my big "homework" need to be done. :)